# Interactive tap-and-hold modal like Instagram? in react native

Tags: react-native

Instagram has a really cool interaction where you can tap-and-hold, aka longPress, on an image and an interactive pop-up appears. Once it appears you can drag your finger to one of the action buttons and removing your finger applies the action and closes the pop-up.

[Like this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3hd.gif)

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Its called peek-and-pop and there are RN navigation libraries which has this feature.

Comment: @parohy: I am searching google from last 3 days and not found any library. Please suggestions if you have any

Comment: Try [wix](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

Comment: @parohy I am using this library already. but Peek and pop only exist for ios. Not for android As you can see Insagram also have different approach for both platforms

Comment: You should follow design guidelines for platform specific. I see that android Instagram has this feature as well. I think you have to implement it by yourself. Check out some modals examples.